# How to wrap X axis labels to multi-lines (X axis label formatting) in ng2-Charts?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

How to wrap x axis labels in to multi-lines (2 lines) in a bar chart made by https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ ?

Expected Result should be like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15240251/37339739-f4450d24-26bb-11e8-90da-e2411034e9ec.png). See the X axis labeling.

Ng2-charts is based on [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) and found following links (PRs) which helps to address this problem.

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/commit/d1b411f4fc2d7b9cafa2d235c9ee008d149a22e3
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/2704

However is it possible to achieve the same in ng2-charts ? Anyone came across this issue when using ng2-charts; if so please let me know how you approach to solve this in angular way.

Comment: Hey! Did you got any solution? if yes will you please share once example? Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some workaround only if you want to wrap labels by spliting by space (" ").

```
scales: {         
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            callback: function(label, index, labels) {
              if (/\s/.test(label)) {
                return label.split(" ");
              }else{
                return label;
              }              
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Chart looks like this now.
[image]

Comment: You can use some regex or text replace/split hack inside the callback method and achieve what you need. At the end you just need to return an array of strings. :)